# How do i share large characters of text via whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I want to share a chunk of text which i am sharing with this code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your score and Some extra text");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The title");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

It works fine but i discovered that once the user chooses share via whats app, the text characters are truncated.

However, i saw this fix online:

```
try{
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="+text+""); 
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Whatsapp Not Installed.", 2000).show();
    }
```

The problem with this code it that it limits sharing to whatsapp only. This is not what i want. How do i share large text from `textview` with the `Intent.createchooser` method?

Comment: How many characters are you trying to share & it gets truncated with whatsapp?

Comment: I am trying up to share up to 5000 characters. I think it get limited at 1000